# How to check formControl value only on submit?

Tags: angular, rxjs

The following code checks the `username` input on valueChanges. How do I check the `username` input only after there's a submit? (i.e., wait for a `submit` event, and don't check on each valueChange?)

```
      this.formCtls['username'].valueChanges.pipe(
        filter<String>(text=>text.length > 2),
        debounceTime(10),
        distinctUntilChanged(), 
        . . .
```

Also, a secondary question that's probably not important enough to open as a whole new question on its own . . . : as above, why is my editor forcing me to add the `<String>` generic next to `filter`? I saw several code snippets online with just:

```
      this.formCtls['username'].valueChanges.pipe(
        filter(text=>text.length > 2),
        debounceTime(10),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
```

but without the `<String>`, my editor (Visual Studio Code) complains that `property 'length' does not exist on type 'unknown'`, and the only way to fix that is to add the `<String>` type after `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind that the field is updated until submit, you can call `updateOn: submit` on the form control, like:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    field1: ['', { updateOn: 'submit'}]
  })

  this.myForm.get('field1').valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(text=>text.length > 2),
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val))
}
```

But with this, the form value does not update this field until submit, so that is important to remember.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jl823x?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

But I don't also see why you couldn't handle some logic for the form control in the submit function as well, if you need to do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution is :**

```
<form name="myForm"> <input ng-model="modelobject" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"> <button id="confirmButton" role="confirm" class="confirm-btn"> Confirm </button> </form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice to see that handled in HTML too.